# Else condition in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know how else can be used without if in nested if condition.I have tried this code on pyCharm editor.

## code:

```
print("Let's find the prime between the interval given...")

start = int(input("\n Enter the Start Point : "))
end = int(input("\n Enter the end Point : "))

for i in range(start, end + 1):
    if i > 1:
        for j in range(2, i):
            if i % j == 0:
                break
#            j = j + 1
        else:
            print(i)
#    start = start + 1

print("Done with checking...")
```

## problem:

My result came but i want to know about else condition in code in detail that how could only else is used.

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstand **`for/else`** with **`if/else`** check below explaination for `for/else`

In python **`for`** loops also have an **`else`** clause which most of us are unfamiliar with. The else clause executes after the loop completes normally. This means that the loop did not encounter a **`break`** statement. They are really useful once you understand where to use them.

This is the basic structure of a for/else loop:

```
for item in container:
    if search_something(item):
        # Found it!
        process(item)
        break
else:
    # Didn't find anything..
    not_found_in_container()
```

Consider [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) simple example which I took from the official documentation:

```
for n in range(2, 10):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print(n, 'equals', x, '*', n/x)
            break
```

It finds factors for numbers between 2 to 10. Now for the fun part. We can add an additional else block which catches the numbers which have no factors and are therefore prime numbers

```
for n in range(2, 10):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print( n, 'equals', x, '*', n/x)
            break
    else:
        # loop fell through without finding a factor
        print(n, 'is a prime number')
```